# Which definition of Likelihood function is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-regression

In the [online version of the Deep Learning book on chapter 5](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) the estimator for likelihood function is defined as:

[image]

That is the product of individual probabilities. After taking the log it arrives at the log-likelihood funciton (***Eq.1***):

[image]

It then rescales the above by dividing it by m to obtain a version expressed as the expected value (***Eq.2***):

[image]

OK. Here is my first question:
The expected value is defined as
[image]

And so I think the expected value of log will be the below expression which is not the same as ***Eq.1*** in the book.

[image]

The only way for this to be true(that is to divide the ***Eq.1*** by m and arrive at ***Eq.2*** as claimed by the book author) is for the probabilities of p(data) to be uniform. But this is also not a valid assumption.
So I don't see what I am missing here?

---

Next, the book argues that maximizing the above log-likelihood function (***Eq.2***) is same as minimizing the KL divergence:

[image]

Or more simply just minimizing the second term. And so the author says that either way we arrive at the same function as ***Eq.2***.

[image]

On the other hand, from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) the cross entropy of two probability is defined as :

[image]

I can understand this definition as the expected value of log(q) which is same as the expression in the ***Eq.2***. but not ***Eq.1***

From the same Wiki page the likelihood definition is given as below which is different than the likelihood function definition from the book(above). Here the probability of q (model) has been raised to the number of occurrences; which then on taking log it is understandable to see it as the expected value.

[image]

So I am confused that first of all which definition of likelihood function is the correct one?
Given the definition from the Wikipedia I can understand that maximizing the log-likelihood function is same as minimizing the cross-entropy function. However I cannot arrive at the same conclusion from the definition of the likelihood and the log-likelihood function given in the book, for the reasons I explained above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 - Equivalence between $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}}\log(p_{model}(x;\theta))$ and $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_{model}(x;\theta))$:**

Yes, as you mentioned in the question, the key issue here is to realize that the following expectation is with respect to the **empirical distribution** defined by the training data ($\hat{p}_{data}$):
$$ \theta_{ML} = \arg\max_{\theta}\mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}} \log(p_{model}(x;\theta)) $$
By [definition](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshashua/papers/class3-ML-MaxEnt.pdf), an empirical distribution assigns a probability of $1/m$ on each of the $m$ points $\mathbb{X} = \{x^{(1)},x^{(2)},...,x^{(m)}\}$ $\to$ Thereby the value of $\hat{p}_{data}(x_i)=\frac{1}{m}f(x_i)$ where $f(x_i)$ represents the ocurrence frequency of a value $x_i$ in our dataset.

Note that a value $x_i$ may appear more than once in our dataset $\mathbb{X}$ $\Rightarrow f(x_i)$ can be $> 1$. This is why we can express the previous expectation as:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}} \log(p_{model}(x;\theta)) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m}\log(p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta))\\
\end{align}$$
Hence, the maximization of both expressions lead to the same value of $\theta_{ML}$

---

**2 - Equivalence between the *minimization* of $D_{KL}(\hat{p}_{data} \Vert p_{model})$ and $H(\hat{p}_{data}, p_{model})$**

As said in the question, the KL divergence of the probability distributions $\hat{p}_{data}$ (empirical distribution of $\mathbb{X}$) and $p_{model}$ (our statistical model that we are using to fit $\mathbb{X}$) is given by the next expression:
$$D_{\text{KL}}(\hat{p}_{data} \parallel p_{model}) = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}} [ 
 \log(\hat{p}_{data}(x)) - \log(p_{model}(x;\theta))]$$

Here, we can see that $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}}  
 \log(\hat{p}_{data}(x))$ does not depend on $\theta$ (it only depends on the data generating process), so it can be trated as a constant. Hence we can adress the same problem of finding the value of $\theta$ that minimizes the cross entropy by minimizing this KL divergence, because this is the same as minimizing:

$$ \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \hat{p}_{data}} [- \log(p_{model}(x;\theta))] = - \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{m}\log(p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta))$$

Which is the definition of the cross entropy $H(\hat{p}_{data}, p_{model})$.

---

**3 - Equivalence between the minimization of $H(\hat{p}_{data}, p_{model})$ and the maximization of $\sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_{model}(x;\theta))$**

Here, we have to proof that
$$\arg\max_{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_{model}(x;\theta))$$
gives the same value of $\theta_{ML}$ than:
$$\begin{align}
\arg\min_{\theta}H(\hat{p}_{data}, p_{model}) &= \arg\min_{\theta}-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta))\\
&= \arg\max_{\theta} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \log(p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta))
\end{align}$$

Both expressions are equivalent (they give the same value of $\theta_{ML}$) because a scale factor (such as $1/m$) does not affect in a minimization/ maximization problem.

---

**4 - Equivalence between $\prod_{i=1}^m p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta)$ and $\prod_{j} p_{model}(x_j;\theta)^{\#\text{ ocurrences of }j}$**

This is because $i$ and $j$ represent different things:

- $i$ represents **each individual datapoint** of a dataset $\mathbb{X}\Rightarrow x^{(i)}$ is a datapoint.
- $j$ represents a certain **value** present in our dataset $\mathbb{X}\Rightarrow x_j$ is a certain value.

Given this, if a *datapoint* $x^{(i)}$ has the same *value* ($x_j$) of other $n$ datapoints, then we can express the likelihood of these datapoints in two equivalent ways:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta) = p_{model}(x_j;\theta)^n$$

So, if we extend this reasoning to all the possible values ($x_j$) that our dataset can have, we reach the equivalency given by wikipedia:
$$\prod_{i=1}^m p_{model}(x^{(i)};\theta) = \prod_{j} p_{model}(x_j;\theta)^{\#\text{ ocurrences of }j}$$

Comment: That was perfect, thanks. But I still have couple of questions. if p(xi)=1/m f(xi), did you not miss multiplying 1/m by f(xi) in your definition of log likelihood ?

Comment: Sure, to what part of the answer are you refering to?

Comment: in part 1, Ex∼p^data log(pmodel(x;θ))=∑1/m log(p model(x;θ))

Comment: That's because the summatory is over the *datapoints* ($x^{(i)}$) and not over the *values* ($x_j$) (following the notation of part 4) present in our dataset $\mathbb{X}$. Thereby, the datapoints that have the same value are sumed  and this has the same effect as multiplying a certain value of $\log(p_{model}(x_j;\theta))$ by $f(x_j)$.